# updating a fragment to achieve facebook like wall android

Tags: android, facebook, android-fragments

This is a theoretical question for the time being as I do not have any code as yet.

As far as I understand fragements they are basically a means of displaying results from an activity, what I am trying to achieve is a automatically updating 'wall' like facebook inside my fragmemt.

Currently I query information from my database from my mainactivity before passing the info to my fragement, as it stands I have only retrieved static content to update an Image and TextView like so:

```
Intent upanel = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
upanel.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
upanel.putExtra("USER_ID",json_user.getString(KEY_UID));
upanel.putExtra("USER_FN",json_user.getString(KEY_FIRSTNAME));
upanel.putExtra("USER_LN",json_user.getString(KEY_LASTNAME));
pDialog.dismiss();
startActivity(upanel);
```

Now, how would one achieve a 'live' update, for instance a drag up to update like in the facebook app?

What should I be researching to achieve this?

Edit

In the spirit of asking an actual question, how do you update a fragment from a JSON request in real time?

Comment: this is actually a pretty interesting question but because you are not asking anything specific it might be closed. This is the kind of thing I would post reddit.com/r/androiddev